# Charsets and "preferred MIME name"

Tags: forms, http, character-encoding, mime, iconv

The HTTP `Accept-Encoding` header contains atoms of acceptable character sets, and the `charset=` field in a MIME `Content-Type` header contains an atom of the character set for the following data.

My question is the following: must these atoms match the preferred MIME encoding name or charset name, or can they match any alias of a charset?

Alias and preferred MIME encoding as used by http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets.

I'm planning on using iconv to convert to platform-native wide UTF, and I don't want to make the entry in the form of an array of fields in the form of (iconv_alias, { list-of-aliases }) per charset. Rather, a simple (alias, iconv_alias) 2-tuple.

Comment: And the question is? And your platform is? And the language you are talking about is?

Comment: Platform and language are irrelevant in this case. Question has been edited for clarity.

Comment: I still don't see a question here..

Comment: The extra "mandated" doesn't really clear up for me what your question is. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, these atoms must IMO match the preferred MIME charset name**, and not just any alias.
Explanations.
I was surprised to see that Google "List of MIME charsets" returned nothing clearer or more useful than the http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets "Character Sets" page from IANA that you mentioned in 2011 and that still seems the best. Ctrl+F"MIME" on that page just returns ONE hit: "Preferred MIME Name", which is the title of the very column you and I are looking for: the list of the charset names that are ACTUALLY used, with very small number of exceptions or errors, in the 350 trillions (i.e. millions of millions) email messages sent EVERY DAY WORLD WIDE. This high level of compliance hence reliability on such a giant number, is due IMO to the email system and its actual norm MIME having got from the beginning a careful attention and intelligent implementation, resulting in 2 fundamental traits:

- the charset is stated ONCE AND ONLY ONCE in each document, namely in the MIME header of each email message, whose existence is ignored from most people since it doesn't cause problems
- the list of the charset names allowed is visibly SHORT, SOLID, INVARIABLE, and nobody strays from it.
  Hereafter are a few:
- us-ascii, iso-8859-1 (initially the standard of the net), utf-8 (now the actual standard), Shift JIS, EUC, ISO-2022-JP, ...

The WEB PAGES are NOT as reliably treated in matter of charsets, for 2 main reasons IMO:

- Only 12 billions web pages are created everyday (3,000x less than email messages), whence the attention given to this is newer (web pages only have existed since 1993, 22 years after email 1971), and, relatively, much smaller
- In each web page, many settings are stated in TWO different places and contexts, the HTML headers (MULTIPLE but corresponding to the SINGLE mime header of email) BUT also MULTIPLE TIMES in the  INSIDE the document. Which inevitably, in a crowd of millions or maybe billions writers, brings a lot of misunderstanding, divergences, confusion, hesitation, incompatibilities, and even errors.

Whence my propositions:

1. YES we all should use ONLY the IANA "Preferred MIME Names", that are already widely sufficient
2. the most important standardization bodies, AFAIK IANA and IETF in this matter, could gather and build an UNIQUE document and list, carefully designed, starting with the current IANA list above but much clearer and shorter, and state it as a norm, widely mediatized so everyone knows it.

Note. There is a big problem, due to the UTF-8 having been imposed in the 1980-90s, with political reasons, against many obvious technical and human reasons. More on this later. Meanwhile UTF-8 brings nothing good or bad in English, little bad in European languages, much complications in other languages like Arabic and Asian ones, even sometimes is others like cyrillic.
Versailles, Thu 27 Apr 2023 18:12:10 +0200, edited (typo) 18h21m50